# sqlite incorrect number of bindings: insert none if no value available

Tags: python, sqlite

I have created a python list with 41 columns and 50 rows.
Now I want to insert this into an SQLite database.
When I execute the database export, I got the error message:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 41, and there are 40 supplied.
```

Most of the list fields should have data. Perhaps one or two don't have any.
Can I write into the sqlite database with a prompt like:
insert if data available, otherwise write none
Or something like this?

My code is like:

```
    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS statstable (
            spielid integer PRIMARY KEY,
41x field descr. (real, integer and text)
            UNIQUE (spielid)
            )
    """)

    c.executemany("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO statstable VALUES (41x ?)", all_data)
```

Comment: How is it supposed to know which column is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Append the appropriate number of `None` values to the nested lists to make them all 41 elements:

```
c.executemany("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO statstable VALUES (41x ?)", 
    [l + [None] * (41 - len(l)) for l in all_data])
```

This assumes the missing elements are always at the end of the list of columns. If they can be different columns in each row, I don't see how you can implement any automatic solution.

If the elements of `all_data` were dictionaries whose keys correspond to column names, you could determine which keys are missing. Then turn it into a list with the `None` placeholders in the appropriate places for those columns.